# python package __init.py__ works alone but when called it breaks

Tags: python, module, package

I am trying to run 'example.py' which imports functions from my mecom package with the following code:

```
from mecom import MeComSerial, ResponseException, WrongChecksum
```

When I run 'example.py' it gives the error

```
MePy\\mecom\__init_\_.py", line 10, in \<module\>
from magic import MeCom, MeComSerial, MeComTcp, VR, VS, Parameter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'magic'
```

when I run the mecom/**init**.py file directly it has no problem importing the magic module. I'm totally stumped here, how can I fix this?

[project file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlhWX.png)

(see included picture of the project files above)

Comment: How are you adding your packages to the import path?

Answer (score 0):

When you run a python program, its parent directory is added to the python path. So, with `example.py`, `mecom` is a package and The .py files in that directory are members of that package. This relative import would work

```
from .magic import MeCom, MeComSerial, MeComTcp, VR, VS, Parameter
```

Note the `.` which makes it a package-relative import. When you executed `mecom.__init__.py` directly, `mecom` is now a directory in the python path. `mecom` is no longer a package, but its .py files are all now regular modules. So your import works.

You should change to package relative imports because you clearly intend `mecom` to be a package.

(Or maybe a subpackage under `MePy` so that `controls` is also in that package. Then, you'd want to pull your example.py back one directory.)